# Does dosfsck -a log errors it found?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, filesystem, fat32

I have a question. Does dosfsck -a log the errors it found? Like, the specifics of the error?

Because, since it's doing it all automatically, it doesn't let the user have input, so I wondered if it logs it all somewhere.

If it doesn't log it, can I make it log what it finds using dosfsck -a?